# how to acess list in a class without an instance of the class?

Tags: c#

I am making a Tennis program in c# for an exam and I need to read a file with players. I can read the players into a list using this code. Now i need to acess the list MalePlayers from another class to get two players from the list and run a match but I can't figure out how to acess it.

```
public class MaleReader
{
    private List<Player> MalePlayers = new List<Player>();
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Delimiter { get; set; }

    public MaleReader(string fn, string delim = "|")
    {
        FileName = fn;
        Delimiter = delim;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var rv = "";
        foreach (var p in MalePlayers)
            rv += "Player: " + p + "\n";
        return rv;
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        TextFieldParser par = new TextFieldParser(FileName);
        par.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        par.SetDelimiters(Delimiter);
        while (!par.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fields = par.ReadFields();
            int MID = Int32.Parse(fields[0]);
            string Firstname = fields[1];
            string MiddleName = fields[2];
            string LastName = fields[3];
            DateTime DoB = DateTime.Parse(fields[4]);
            string Country = fields[5];
            string ShortCountry = fields[6];

            //Gender gender =
            var p = new Player(MID, Enums.Gender.Male, Firstname, MiddleName, LastName, DoB, Country, ShortCountry);
            MalePlayers.Add(p);

        }
        par.Close();
    }

    public static void RunPlayerReaderMale()
    {
        var f = new MaleReader(@"C:\Users\R0ede\Dropbox\Git\Examprogram\Data\FemalePlayer.txt");
        f.Load();
        //Console.WriteLine(f);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do without making an instance of the class?

Comment: No, if you don't have an instance of the class, the `List<Player> MalePlayers` doesn't exist

Comment: @R0ede Based on your current context. I'd use Rubens Farias approach below by making the `RunPlayerReaderMale()` method return `List<Player>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why don't you have an instance of the class `MaleReader`? I assume you had to create it to load players from the file.

I would either keep the instance you used to read the file, or, if you don't want to keep it, extract the `List` before you get rid of the instance.

Or you can take the static aproach, as others mentioned.

Comment: how would you go about extracting the list?

Comment: Well, make the list public, or create a getter to it. After calling `MaleReader.Load()`, simply assign the list to any variable you need to. Do you want me to make an example?

Answer (score 2):

You have several ways to do that, and most of them are just a style choice.

One option would be create a static method which internally creates the `MaleReader` instance but it only returns its `MalePlayers` property.

```
public static List<Player> RunPlayerReaderMale()
{
    var f = new MaleReader(@"C:\Users\R0ede\Dropbox\Git\Examprogram\Data\MalePlayer.txt");
    f.Load();
    return f.MalePlayers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only do that by making it: `public static List<Player> MalePlayers = new List<Player>();`

But you need to understand what you're doing here, making this list `static` means that **all instances of your class will share the same List**.